# How can I search the changes made on a `s3` bucket between two timestamp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using `s3` bucket to store my data. And I keep pushing data to this bucket every single day. I wonder whether there is feature I can compare the files different in my bucket between two date. I not, is there a way for me to build one via `aws cli` or `sdk`?

The reason I want to check this is that I have a s3 bucket and my clients keep pushing data to this bucket. I want to have a look how much data they pushed since the last time I load them. Is there a pattern in aws support this query? Or do I have to create any rules in s3 bucket to analyse it?

Comment: Can you tell us more about _why_ you are seeking this information? There might be a better way to provide what you are actually seeking (eg realtime notification via Lambda functions). Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Added more information about the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Listing from Amazon S3**

You can activate [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily file listing the contents of an Amazon S3 bucket. You could then compare differences between two inventory files.

**List it yourself and store it**

Alternatively, you could **list the contents of a bucket** and look for objects dated since the last listing. However, if objects are deleted, you will only know this if you keep a list of objects that were previously in the bucket. It's probably easier to use S3 inventory.

**Process it in real-time**

Instead of thinking about files in batches, you could configure Amazon S3 Events to trigger something whenever a new file is uploaded to the Amazon S3 bucket. The event can:

- Trigger a notification via Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS), such as an email
- Invoke an AWS Lambda function to run some code you provide. For example, the code could process the file and send it somewhere.